# Discord does not send specific message

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm currently in the process of making a Discord bot. I want it to be able to access an API with a specific query, and then display the response in chat. For this, I made this command:

```
    commands.CreateCommand("card").Parameter("user", ParameterType.Unparsed).Do(async (e) =>
    {
        string message = e.Args[0];

        await e.Channel.SendMessage("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/" + message + "?collectible=1");

        var r = await Get<RootObject>("https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/" + message + "?collectible=1");
        Console.Write("Hold it!\n");
        await e.Channel.SendMessage(r.img);
    });
```

And the function it references:

```
    public async Task<RootObject> Get<RootObject>(string url)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Mashape-Key", "xxxxx");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
            Console.Write("Hang on!\n");
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            Console.Write("Not so fast!\n");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }
    }
```

But when I send the command, it only sends back the first link as well as the Hang on and Not so fast messages. The message I want, r.img, just doesn't send. How can I change the code so it responds with the info I want?

The response, by the way:

```
[  
   {  
      "cardId":"EX1_572",
      "dbfId":"1186",
      "name":"Ysera",
      "cardSet":"Classic",
      "type":"Minion",
      "faction":"Neutral",
      "rarity":"Legendary",
      "cost":9,
      "attack":4,
      "health":12,
      "text":"At the end of your turn, add_a Dream Card to_your hand.",
      "flavor":"Ysera rules the Emerald Dream.  Which is some kind of green-mirror-version of the real world, or something?",
      "artist":"Gabor Szikszai",
      "collectible":true,
      "elite":true,
      "race":"Dragon",
      "playerClass":"Neutral",
      "img":"http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/EX1_572.png",
      "imgGold":"http://media.services.zam.com/v1/media/byName/hs/cards/enus/animated/EX1_572_premium.gif",
      "locale":"enUS"
   }
]
```

And RootObject.cs:

```
namespace DiscordBot
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string cardId { get; set; }
        public string dbfId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string cardSet { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string faction { get; set; }
        public string rarity { get; set; }
        public int cost { get; set; }
        public int attack { get; set; }
        public int health { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string flavor { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public bool collectible { get; set; }
        public bool elite { get; set; }
        public string race { get; set; }
        public string playerClass { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string imgGold { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with c#, it's a problem in the library you are using. I suggest you to debug your code and see what's going on

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I put pauses all over the statements, and while it does pause in the Get<RootObject> function and when executing said function, it does not pause in the statements right after. [Here's where it paused, the second and third pause from the top didn't register.](http://i.imgur.com/wKzZPth.png)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Nothing weird in the debug data though, at least nothing blatantly obvious.

Comment: Is the Get function returning properly? It seems to me that the JsonConvert might be throwning an exception. Look at the Output window for clues

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Hey, you seem to be right. The output message is: 

Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Then the problem is that what you are getting as response cannot be deserialized into the expected class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's weird. I formed the RootObject class straight from json2csharp.com, but maybe that left something weird in there. I edited the post to show the entirety of RootObject.cs.

Comment: is that a response as 'described in documentation' or an actual response. Often API's send along other fields such as success, code, content. where content would be the object you are showing. Also, you might want to remove your api key, who knows what people want/can do with it/

Comment: @MXD This response is copied directly from a Console.Write(json.ToString()); call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Json you provided starts with a **[** which indicates it's an array as opposed to when it starts with an **{** which indicates an object.

So instead of

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

You should use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
```